# How to store CodeBuild output artifact in S3 bucket folder with the folder name as build-date

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

I have a codebuild project which creates a binary distribution wheel stored in the `dist` directory.

My Codebuild project buildspec [relevant lines]

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - "*.whl"
  name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  #discard-paths: yes
  base-directory: 'dist'
```

Artifacts

- Type: S3
- Bucketname:
- Name:
- Path: path/to/folder/in/s3/bucket
- Artifact packaging: None

The codebuild project runs successfully but the output artifact is not in the directory with the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the folder name as defined in the `buildspec.yml`, the semantic versioning needs to be enabled.

I had to enable that in the Artifacts section of the CodeBuild project[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
# Artifacts
  artifacts:
    locaton            = aws_s3_bucket.myapp-project.bucket
    type               = "S3"        
    name               = "YourFilename.json"
    path               = "assets/translations/"
    packaging          = "NONE"
```

In Summary, your missing the S3 bucket location if you are not using a codepipeline.  A similar article can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66767863/codebuild-artifacts-in-a-s3-subfolder/72365272#72365272)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31854062)